# Mongoose error: The uri parameter to openuri() must be string, got "object". Make sure the first parameter to mongoose.connect() is a string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

Why am I getting this error if i have connected to databases before this way?

Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Player = require('../models/player');   //import player database  

const db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@ds263493.mlab.com:63493/user', { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; //Promise type avoids warnings mongoose throws
mongoose.connect(db, function(err)
{
    if(err){
        console.error("Error! "+ err);
    }
});

router.get('/players', function(req, res)               //make req to players
{
    console.log('Get request for all players');
    Player.find({})                                     //connected to players collection in database
    .exec(function(err, players)                        //once players are found, send as response to browser
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log("Error retrieving players");
        }
        else
        {
            res.json(players);
        }
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

I changed the username and password for database to default, just for this question, that is not the problem.

Somehow it is saying the parameter for mongoose.connect("") is not a string when it is, i even tried useNewUrlParser:true, but it is still giving me same error.

Comment: Not sure where you saw that syntax, but it's `mongoose.connect(<uri>,<options>, function(err) { ...` You called `connect` twice, and tried to pass the result in the second time. Just do it once correctly.

Comment: @NeilLunn i see, i didn't notice i was connecting twice. Worked for the guy who did the youtube video...haha. Thanks!!

Comment: I would advise referencing official documentation over some video. The documentation could be improved to actually say this, but the recommended way is with the [callback/Promise implementation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#callback). Legacy forms which don't force you to actually await the connection have reliability issues, and other potential pitfalls in your code unless you really know what you are doing.